# How to convert list of strings to multiple objects

Tags: arrays, json, object

here are the strings

```
[ 
 "Package: libslf4j-java", 
  "Status: install ok installed", 
  "Homepage: http://www.slf4j.org/", 
  "", 
  "Package: libplexus-sec-dispatcher-java", 
  "Status: install ok installed", 
  "Homepage: https://github.com/sonatype/plexus-sec-dispatcher", 
  "", 
  "Package: libtext-wrapi18n-perl", 
  "Status: install ok installed", 
  "Homepage: http://search.cpan.org/search?module=Text::WrapI18N", 
  "", 
  "Package: java-common", 
  "Status: install ok installed", 
  "", 
  "Package: libantlr-java", 
  "Status: install ok installed", 
  "Homepage: http://www.antlr2.org/", 
  "", 
]
```

I want to divide it to objects, so the final result should be

```
[ 
    { 
      Package: "libslf4j-java", 
      Status: "install ok installed", 
      Homepage: "http://www.slf4j.org/" 
    }, 
    { 
      Package: "libplexus-sec-dispatcher-java", 
      Status: "install ok installed", 
      Homepage: "https://github.com/sonatype/plexus-sec-dispatcher" 
    }, 
    { 
      Package: "java-common", 
      Status: "install ok installed", 
      Homepage: "" 
    }, 
    { 
      Package: " libantlr-java", 
      Status: "install ok installed", 
      Homepage: "http://www.antlr2.org/" 
    } 
  ]
```

I tried reduce,split, map, but I cannot figured it out. Thank you in advance to those who will answer!

Comment: Welcome to SO. JSON is a very generic concept. In what platform do you need this?

Comment: As seen from the question your object is itself a single-dimensional array, and you need to create array of objects with the group of 3 elements each from the array.

Comment: Your don't have object. You have list of strings. For some reason it seems that empty element is separator, but then you must rely on order of you element. Also there is missing element, how do you know what is missing? You must loop your array and parse every line

Answer (score 0):

You have one huge array, so loop it and parse it's elements:

```
var result = [];
var currentElement = {};
var allKeys = new Set();

currentArray.forEach(function (value) {
    if (value === '') {
        result.push(currentElement);
        currentElement = {};

        return;
    }

    let parts = value.split(':');

    let key = parts.shift();
    let value = parts.join(':');

    currentElement[key] = value;
    allKeys.add(key);
})
```

---

Then loop `allKeys` and `result` to add missing keys